# Relativity, communication and reference frames

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, information

Quick question here.

Does communication in special relativity involve sending signals from contrasting reference frames? I gather reference frames aren't really physical things, they're mathematical tools to describe an obsvers observations.. Like it's a convention..

Interactions of course take time. Light, sound, etc, signals take time. So everything we perceive is in the past a little bit. But these signals come from other obsverers within their own frames of reference. They receive signals at different times to me and the apply different time coordinates to the emission of the signals.

Does special relativity change this in any way, I gather we can apply contrasting coordinates to when the event happened associated.

Is there anything here that really changes how we think of human communication prior to the development of relativity.

Comment: It's unclear what the intent is here: are you interested in deep space communication or flash trading, where c matters, or are you interesting in the interpretation of Gedanken Experiments in SR, in which case many a Gedankaneer has been tripped up by the nuances?

Comment: I think I'm. A Gedankaneer here ahaha

Answer (score 1):

In the analysis of the famous relativity paradoxes, thinking about the delay of light can lead to confusion, particularly with the colloquial use of the word "see", which has an obvious associating with light.

Special relativity is self consistent, so there are no contradictions, and when analyzed in Minkowski space, there are no apparent contradictions (aka: paradoxes). For example, the Twin Paradox: integrate $d\tau$ along the world-line: Done. Nothing to see here.

In a paradox-situation, you choose various inertial frames and find things that appear to not make sense. An inertial frame is more than a mathematical abstraction: it is a split of Minkowski space into a 3-space and 1 time dimension. That is, it defines the observer's definition of "Everywhere" and "Now" for all values of "now"

Since resources are cheap in thought experiments, the observer sitting at $(t, 0, 0, 0)$ does not need to wait for light signal to "see" an event. Rather, he has an infinite lattice of graduate students with calibrated rulers and synchronized clocks measuring events locally, and reporting back after the fact. The resolution of the Twin Paradox occurs when you realize traveling twin's lattice of clocks go totally out of synch at turn-around, and must be recalibrated with a distance dependent bias correction.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to worry about reference frames for light and other EM signals - they travel at c for everyone!

Comment: But do obsverers communicate between their ideas of now through signals?

Comment: The transmitter and receiver are each instantaneously at a point (you are expected to know where they are!), but their "velocity" is irrelevant.  The communications are point-to-point.  Does that help?  If you are confused, you might be "over-thinking" this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might find the following helpful. I should start by saying that my explanation will be from the perspective of special relativity. Things can become much more complicated when you consider the curvature effects of general relativity.

Firstly, relativistic effects come about only when there is relative motion. If you and I are at rest relative to each other, then according to SR we share the same direction of time axis in spacetime. So if we synchronise our watches in the right way, when it says 12 O'clock on my watch it will also say 12 O'clock on your watch. We each exist on the same plane of simultaneity, regardless ion how far apart we might be. If we exchange information, there will be a time lag as the signal moves between us, but that is no different in principle to the time lag that would occur if you lived a mile from me and I posted a letter to you that did not arrive until the following day.

If you and I are moving relative to each other, then we no longer have parallel time axes, and we no longer share a common plane of simultaneity. For you when it is 12 O'clock there is a level slice through spacetime on which it is 12 O'clock everywhere in your frame. But that slice through time is actually a sloping one in my frame, the slope being in the direction of my movement relative to you.

That slope accounts for two famous effects of special relativity, known as time dilation and length contraction.  There are many other questions and answers on this site that explain how those three things are linked, so I won't repeat that here.

Essentially, if you are passing me at a sufficiently high speed when it is twelve O'clock on your watch and 12 O'clock on mine, we will each claim that it is also 12 O'clock on the moon, say, but my 12 O'clock on the moon might be a different time from your 12 O'clock on the moon- let's suppose the difference is 2 minutes (in fact the difference would depend on our relative speed), so I might think an event happened on the moon at 14:30 by my watch and you would say it happened at 14:32 (or perhaps 14:28, depending on which direction you are moving in). The fact that we label the event with different times is just that- a labelling issue. The event only happens once at a given point in spacetime- we just happen to label it with a different time coordinate.

So if we are moving relative to each other, and a long way apart, and we want to make sense of the times at which we each think we have sent and received messages, then we need to take account of both the propagation time and the fact that we  use different time labels to refer to points in time at different places.

Comment: What does the contrasting time coordinates for events have to do with time dilation, I visualise say my clock slowing down relative to yours for example and then we witness the same event but my clock says 14:25 and yours says 14:30. We both exist in the same universe here but since my time has been dilated then we observe them at contrasting times

Comment: Not too relevant, but I saw a post on here relating these contrasting planes with changing how we think of the experience of other observers.. Do you agree with this or does nothing here change

Comment: To answer your first comment, see any of the related Q&A on this site. To answer the second, you ned to tell me which post you are talking about so I can look at it.

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/96564/how-meaningful-is-the-notion-of-now-here-on-earth the guy who posted here seemed pretty shook up. I saw the convo you guys had on private too...

Comment: Aaah I think I'm onto something it seems to be that yes that is kind of the case, the contrasting values on our clock come from our differing proper times. Which are different due to the paths we took through spacetime